# Have someone an experience with write output into SFTP by Data Flow Python SDK?

Tags: python, sftp, google-cloud-dataflow

My pipeline have to write into SFTP as text output.
I wonder if writing custom sink is the only option for it?

Is there any other option? (For instance:extending 'TextIO.Write'....)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an existing sink that supports SFTP, so you would need to look at writing a custom sink, possibly based on one of the existing file-based sinks such as `TextIO.Write`.